# Get the contents of a note from Apple Notes programmatically

Tags: icloud, applescript, command-line, bash, notes.app

I want to get the contents of a note from Apple Notes programmatically. Any solutions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `sqlite3` works on `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite`

Comment: All you ever wanted to know about scripting the Notes application is here https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/notes/index.html

Comment: I don't think any of the linked question's answers are particularly helpful.  Here's an AppleScript as an example way to do it. `set noteName to "Test Note"
set accountName to "put_account_name_here"
tell application "Notes"
 tell account accountName
  get body of note noteName
 end tell
end tell
`